# How to query XML inside a tag?

Tags: java, xml, xquery, xquery-sql, exist-db

I am trying to query the value for location with the *attribute* tag in my `xml` below. How can I do so?

My current query only returns the value for the **full** attribute tag but I only want the value for location, which in this case is *"sampleLocation"?*

i.e:  `location="sampleLocation"`

**XML:**

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <name>Sample name</name>
        <attribute id="sampleid" location="sampleLocation" type="sampleType"/>
    </product>
</Products>
```

**Current code:**

```
  public String getLocationByName(String name) {
        final String nameToQueryFor = name;
        return engine.new Query<String>(MY_COLLECTION) {

            @Override
            protected String query(Collection collection) throws Exception {
                XQueryService service = queryService();

                ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query(
                        format("//Products/Product[name='%s']" +
                                        "/attribute"
                                , StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(nameToQueryFor)
                        ));

                List<String> results = newArrayList();

                for (String resource : new IterableStringResources(resourceSet)) {
                    results.add(resource);
                }
                return results.get(0);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following query:

```
"//Products/Product[name='%s']/attribute/@Location/string()"
```

which returns: "sampleLocation"

Note: without using the `/string()` at the end it was giving the error:

```
attribute 'Location' has no parent element
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited for the 'location' + correction]

```
"//Products/Product/name[text()=%s]/next-sibling::attribute/a‌​ttribute::location"
```

Translation: in the context of `//Products/Product` select the element `<name>` with a given text. Then take the next sibling element with the `<attribute>` type from which get the value of the `location` attribute (of this element)

Some examples of 'xpath location paths' [straight from the horse's mouth](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths).

Comment: Will this not pull back all the values for attribute, I only want location?

Comment: @java123999 Corrected to select only the `location` attribute of the `<attribute>` element node (gosh, this sound fantastic when read aloud). Let me know, please.

Comment: this isn't giving me any results back, can you please check it is correct? or do I need to use: following-sibling::chapter[position()=1]

Comment: Being the single sibling of `attribute` type, it shouldn't. Maybe try: `//Products/Product[name='%s']/following-sibling::attribute/attribute::location`

Comment: ok, I don't think it is a single sibling as there is also " type" ?#

Comment: Ah Scheiße. The mistake is in another place. Try this `//Products/Product/name[text()=%s]/next-sibling::attribute/attribute::location`. Translation: in the context of `//Products/Product` select the element `<name>` with a given text. Then take the next sibling element of the `<attribute>` type and get the value of the `location` attribute of this element.

Comment: what does next sibling do? I have simplified my code for example purpose, there is actually a few other tags between name and attribute?

Comment: Please see my answer I was able to get a solution for this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is

```
//Product[child::name/text()={$nameToQueryFor}]/attribute/@location
```

This will only work when the variable is bound to a value for the element type

Comment: "This will only work when the variable is bound to a value for the element type " - what does this mean?

Comment: Please see my answer I was able to get a solution for this, thanks